# How to change color of Image within SwiftUI Picker menu-item?

Tags: macos, swiftui, colors, picker

I am writing a picker and it lists a bunch of icons.

```
Picker("Icons ", selection: $selectedIcon) {
    ForEach(icons, id: \.self) { icon in
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: icon)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red) // This doesn't work
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

In the above code, SwiftUI picker doesn't change the color of the icon to red in the picker's menu-item as per foreground color.
Any idea how to change color of an image within picker menu-item?

Comment: Try using `.renderingMode(.template)` before defining your foreground color

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using `.foregroundStyle(.red, .blue)`,
works for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.foregroundStyle(Color1, Color2)`
But only `Color1` will be displayed.